# Isomorphism between $L^2$ and direct sum of $L^2$ spaces with mutually singular measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove the next proposition but I have some troubles:

If $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ are mutually singular Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu=\mu_{1}+\mu_{2},$ then $L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mu)$ is naturally isomorphic to $L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mu_{1})\bigoplus L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mu_{2}).$

First, how are the elements in the direct sum with respect to the other space $L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mu)?$

I guess that the next equality holds:
$$L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mu_{1})\bigoplus L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mu_{2})=L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mu)$$ because of the projection theorem, but I'm not sure about this owing to my question. In such case is enough to prove that orthogonal complement of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mu_{1})$ is the other space $L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mu_{2}),$ but I'm stuck in this.

I think the key is the descomposition $f=f(1-\chi_{A})+f\chi_{A},$ where $A$ is a measurable set such that $\mu_{1}(A)=0=\mu_{2}(\mathbb{R}\setminus A).$

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: It's $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mu) \cong L^2(\mathbb{R}\setminus A,\mu_1) \oplus L^2(A,\mu_2)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: But since $\mu_1(A) = 0$, you have $L^2(\mathbb R, \mu_1) \cong L^2(\mathbb R \setminus A, \mu_1)$.

Comment: Good point @gerw.